# How can get S3 files from presigned url and upload that content to another bucket

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I want to upload image using pre-signed URL from one bucket to the another bucket.
First bucket has its own pre-signed URL, by using this URL need to upload the image on s3 bucket. Basically avoid download file. I need to do this using java spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is a presigned URL to download from the source bucket, you won't be able to upload this (or any other) file to the destination bucket.

If you have an access token with permissions both to read from source and write to destination, you can generate a presigned URL on the destination bucket which would [copy a certain file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/copy-object.html) from the source bucket.

To do this, include `x-amz-copy-source=sourcebucket/sourcefile` as a parameter to the URL of the target file and sign this URL.

The copy operation will be triggered by a issuing a `PUT` request to this URL with an empty body.